# nodeJS POST method using request

Tags: node.js, post, request

I am using a POST method to pass some header variables for a REST API:

```
const request = require('request');    
const options = {
    url: 'https://klk.in.edst.com/apiserver/api/v1/ask/search/docs',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/raw',
       'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
     },
    body: {
           "apiToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLVBHAMiJ9.Ijg0ZWY0Y2ViLWVkN2EtNGE4My04N2RhLWViYmMxYjkyNzI3YSI.r5Tlccb09MyKV9DFQrDxvSyMHqOxe3VzKXucz5BYm7-ivxeRiFEBwBsBnesgrYstxzTFG-psyes2GmPO2IrHyA",
           "question": "SAM",
           "stopWords": "false",
           "language":"en",
           "start": "0",
           "rows": "2",
           "project": {"projectId":"1752","projectName":"DIRECT_COG3"}
          }
 };

request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    //console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`);
    //res.write(response.statusCode.toString());
    console.log(body);
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Argument error, options.body.
    at setContentLength (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\request.js:437:28)
    at Request.init (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\request.js:442:5)
    at new Request (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\request.js:127:8)
    at request (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
    at Function.post (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\index.js:61:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\technology\UI4\cog_server5.js:21:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
_http_outgoing.js:653
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:653:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:621:15)
    at Request.write (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\request.js:1494:27)
    at end (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\request.js:549:18)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\technology\UI4\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I am able to get the response via a REST tool. Any help in forming a valid header would be appreciated.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2):

you must stringify the body before sending, and also update `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, as below, **don't ever put your token keys on Open forum**

body: JSON.stringify({
"apiToken": "API_TOKEN",
"question": "SAM",
"stopWords": "false",
"language":"en",
"start": "0",
"rows": "2",
"project": {"projectId":"1752","projectName":"DIRECT_COG3"}
})

Comment: The token keys are invalid as well as the url. Thanks for the reply. It solved the header issue, now I get this error: `<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object
```

You're giving it an object and request does not know what to do with it.

If you're attempting to send JSON, you're actually sending a Javascript object; use `JSON.stringify` on the object to make it a JSON.

```js
const options = {
    ...
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ...
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the header error. But I get the below error in the response: `<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @RedwoodThomas It might be because "application/raw" is not a valid content type, the only valid content type for JSON is "application/json".

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Works fine now.

Comment: @RedwoodThomas If you find a Stack Overflow answer helpful, be sure to mark it as accepted.